# Desktop Icons rearranged when hiding Taskbar Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, desktop-icons, hide

I recently noticed that when I toggled the taskbar visibility in Windows 10 that all my desktop icons are rearranged.

[image]

When restoring the visibility of the taskbar (unhiding it), the desktop icons are returned to their normal positions.

Is there anyway to prevent this odd behavior? Why is this happening?

Running Windows 10 Pro version 21H1, OS build 19043.1586

Comment: “Why is this happening?” - At the most basic level, by hiding the taskbar, your desktop gets slightly larger and you have auto arrange enabled so icons are adjusted accordingly

Comment: @Ramhound that's the thing; auto arrange is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

**Ensure your screen is not changing scale** - that will cause this.  Ensure your screen resolution supports hiding the taskbar without changing size.   That is a normal way to set desktop size and scale.

**Then run DISM and SFC:**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**Test a new Windows User Account / Profile.**

Them if there are still issues, try a new user account and see if the strange behaviour occurs in the new User Account.

The easiest (not only) fix for a damaged user Profile is to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: How does one go about ensuring that the screen is not changing scale? Do you mean the monitor resolution?

Comment: I set the scale in Settings and do not adjust it.  That is why I mentioned testing a new User Profile.

Answer (score 1):

Hold CTRL and scroll mouse wheel, desktop icons will change in size and rearrange back.

Comment: They do change in size, but they still are all jumbled out of position.